# awk/sed solution for printing only next line after it matches a pattern

Tags: awk, sed, file-manipulation

I have multiple files in a folder. This is how a file look like
File1.txt

```
ghfgh gfghh
  dffd  kjkjoliukjkj
  sdf ffghf
  sf 898575
  sfkj utiith

## 
my data to be extracted
```

I want to extract the line immediately below "##" pattern from all the files and write them to an output file. I want the file name to be appended too in the output file. 
Desired output

```
>File1
My data to be extracted
>File2
My data to be extracted
>File3
My data to be extracted 

This is what i tried 
awk '/##/{getline; print FILENAME; print ">"; print}' *.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: if you're considering using getline in future then make sure you understand everything discussed in http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline before deciding to do so.

Answer (score 4):

assumes one extract per file (otherwise filename header will be repeated)

```
$ awk '/##/{f=1; next} f{print ">"FILENAME; print; f=0}' *.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: That doesn't produce any output.

Comment: it writes to `output.txt`

Comment: Output.txt is empty

Comment: did you try with the posted sample file?  I don't see anything wrong with the script.  Perhaps your files are not what they are supposed to be?

Comment: I tried with my actual file which is similar to the sample file here

Comment: **similar** is not a synonym for **same**.  Save the posted contents in "File1.txt" named file and test the script with that.

Comment: You are right! My bad. Thanks for the solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'print ">$ARGV\n", scalar <> if /^##/' -- *.txt > output.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `$ARGV` contains the current input file name
- `scalar <>` reads one line from the input

Answer (score 1):

a quick way with grep:

```
grep -A1 '##' *.txt|grep -v '##' > output.txt
```

Comment: This is how outpur looks like                                                                     File1.txt:##                                                                                                         
File1.txt-my data to be extracted

Comment: I would add the `-H` option, and change the 2nd grep to `sed '/##/d;/--/d;s/^/>/;s/-/\n/'`

Answer (score 0):

POSIX or GNU sed:

```
$ sed -n '/^##/{n;p;}' file
my data to be extracted
```

grep and sed:

```
$ grep -A 1 '##' file | sed '1d'
my data to be extracted
```